# nodejs I don't export this variable or ever use it and yet it loads every time I run the project. why?

Tags: node.js, json, request

So I am pouring through some json and using node.js. I figured for readability there should be individual classes/controller things for some of the data I'm collecting. I keep all the categories in a file called categories.js. when I require categories.js it has certain processes that run every single time even if I don't export them. I included some code below if anyone could explain why.

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'working url',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'working auth'
  },
  'contentType': 'application/json'
};

var name = function() {
  console.log('from var name')
  // only runs if called
};

var whyDoesThisRun = request(options, function (error, response) {
    console.log('why does this run every time the file is loaded?')
   // always runs
});

function thing(){
  console.log('from function thing')
  // only runs when called
};

module.export = {
  categoriesClass: thing()
}
```

from app.js

```
const categoriesClass = require('working url for above')
```

so yeah every time I run the project I get 'from function thing()' printed out just like I export. but it also prints out 'why does this run every time the file is loaded' every single time even though it isn't exported or called anywhere in the project. can someone explain why this variable is always called and how to prevent it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do

```
var whyDoesThisRun = request(options, function (error, response) {
    console.log('why does this run every time the file is loaded?')
   // always runs
});
```

which can be looked at more simply like

```
var whyDoesThisRun = request(someArgs);
```

You call `request` and assign the return value to `whyDoesThisRun`. Even with no other code, that *will* run if the module gets imported anywhere.

```js
const request = () => console.log('request running');

var whyDoesThisRun = request();
```

If you wanted the function to only run when called, make it a higher-order function:

```
var whyDoesThisRun = () => request(options, function (error, response) {
    console.log('request finished')
});
```

This way, a request will only be made when `whyDoesThisRun()` is encountered.